# Jekyll and custom css

Tags: css, ruby, blogs, jekyll

Is there a way to include custom css tags in a jekyll site while using markdown for the entry files; for example, when I want to highlight a certain paragraph?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on exactly what you want? Both ScottHelm and @berkes have provided very valid solutions, but it is hard to recommend a particular one unless we know more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Peterb have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501185/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-markdown-using-jekyll - tested and worked with custom css "`.float-right`" on an image added to post with md: `{: .float-right}![](/path/to/img)`

Answer (score 16):

Markdown nor YAML FrontMatter have this built in. But you can make it yourself.

Say, you have foo.css that you want to include on certain posts.

In `_posts/2013-02-03-higligting-foo.markdown`:

```
---
css: foo
title: "Drupal Imagecache security vulnarability with DDOS attack explained"
tags: [drupal, imagecache, security, ddos]
---
```

Then, in `_layouts/default.html`:

```
{% if post && post.css %}
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='public/assets/{{ post.css }}.css' />
{% endif %}
```

If a post is shown, and the post has a variable defined, css, then use that to include the css file with the name. Note that this does not test wether the filename is correct, whether the css-file exists and so on.

Comment: post should be changed to page and {% post.css %} should be {{ page.css }}.

Comment: @duleorlovic: Is that a recent change, or did I simply post something wrong? Have you got a link to some doc. on this?

Comment: {% ... %}  is for things that do not resolve to text (ie. if/for/unless)  ----- {{...}} is for text emission

Comment: I used what suggested by @duleorlovic ({{ page.css }}) but I am in octopress. Is this the difference ? Is it page or post finally ? ***NB:*** in Octopress you have to edit `source/_includes/custom/head.html` with the lines above, using page (not post) and place the included css must be placed at the root: `{{ root_url }}/{{ page.css }}.css`

Answer (score 5):

If you mean can you give a particular paragraph in your Markdown document a specific class, you technically can, by just typing the paragraph tag the way you want it:

```
My **first** paragraph

<p class="mySpecialClass">My **second** paragraph</p>

My **third** paragraph
```

and Markdown will pass your `p` tag through to the resulting HTML.

However, Markdown gives up on parsing content inside tags you type yourself, so your paragraph's content won't be treated as Markdown — e.g. the word `**second**` in that paragraph won't show up as bold.

I switched to Textile for Jekyll posts because of this behaviour.

Good luck!

Comment: The kramdown engine does offer the option to embed markdown in HTML tags. Just do `parse_block_html: true` in config.yml or front matter

Comment: @jasonszhao does that work for Github Pages?  That'd be great.

Comment: [kramdown is supported by Github Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/migrating-your-pages-site-from-maruku/). However, I only upload my compiled directory, and I'm not completely sure that that option works.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to put html tags in your markdown document, and it should parse them no problem.  for example:

```
#This

is a paragraph <span style="background-color:yellow">with highlighting</span>
```

Comment: @rorra Why would you approve the edit to this post?  It is clearly meant as a comment, but is not so.