# How to add multiple classes to MarkDown using Jekyll?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, markdown, jekyll

I want to produce HTML table in Jekyll driven web site.

The table is to be formatted with `table` and `table-stripped` classes like this:

```
<table class="table table-stripped">
```

How can I do it?

Similar problem: how to add multiple CSS classes to paragraph in MarkDown used in Jekyll?

Answer (score 28):

I have found the following solutions:

```
{: .table .table-striped}
|Port  | Content served by | queries/second |
| ------------------------------------------|
| 80   | Apache            | 130            |
| 8080 | Varnish           | 6200           |


{: .aaa .bbb}
Lorem ipsum...
```

Comment: Classes to HTML elements are attributes. You can get more information how to add attributes to Markdown elements when using Kramdown (the parser used by Jekyll) at http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#attribute-list-definitions.

Comment: You can accept your answer if this solved your problem for you.